# add_input_ext generates an error in recent versions of latexmk

Tags: latexmk

I am trying to build a document which depends on some SVG files. I want these SVG files to be converted to PDF, and then the resulting PDF used as inputs to the compilation. For this purpose I have been using `latexmk`, with the `latexmkrc` below:

```
sub svg2pdf {
   my $curdir = cwd();
   system("inkscape -D --export-pdf=\"$curdir/$_[0].pdf\" \"$curdir/$_[0].svg\"");
}
add_input_ext( 'latex', 'pdf' );
$pdf_mode = 1;
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex %O -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %S';
```

This works great on my personal machine which has `latexmk` v4.41 installed. However, it doesn't work on the machine I have to use in my office, which has `latexmk` v4.65; I get the error:

```
Latexmk: Initialization file 'latexmkrc' gave an error:
     Undefined subroutine &main::add_input_ext called at (eval 7) line 6, <GEN0> chunk 1.

Latexmk: Stopping because of problem with rc file
```

I get the same error in fact if I strip down the `latexmkrc` to contain only the line `add_input_ext( 'latex', 'pdf' );`

So my question is: what's the simplest way, using `latexmk` v4.65, to get the functionality I had in `latexmk` v4.41? (Or if this is impossible, what's the simplest workflow that would achieve my goal of building the document using these SVG files as source?)

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(`Latexmk` maintainer here.) How to get a working `latexmkrc`:

1. Just remove the line with `add_input_ext`.  Even in versions of `latexmk` that implement it, the use of `add_input_ext` to add the extension `pdf` is not needed because that's already one of input extensions that `latexmk` has configured itself to use for `pdflatex`.
2. But do insert the line

   ```
   add_cus_dep( 'svg', 'pdf', 0, 'svg2pdf' );
   ```

Without it, `latexmk` would not know that a missing `pdf` file is to be made from an `svg` file.  That is equally true for v. 4.41 of `latexmk`.  Since the OP's configuration did work with that version, presumably the `add_cus_dep` line is present in the actual `latexmkrc`.

Despite the lack of need for `add_input_ext` in this case, the question does show that there is error in the `latexmk` documentation (at v. 4.65), which does mention this subroutine (and also some configuration variables that no longer exist).  I'll correct the documentation in the next release.

The `add_input_ext` subroutine got removed (at v. 4.62), because its implementation interfered with the simplest implementation of some other changes I made. These were to automatically handle the situation where a document uses `\pdfoutput` to change the kind of output file that is made by `latex` or `pdflatex`. But I had forgotten that the subroutine was documented.  Perhaps I should reinstate `add_input_ext`.

The reason that `latexmk` has a list of possible input extensions is that the `\includegraphics` macro of LaTeX can be used without an input extension for the file, and then `pdflatex` looks for files with a certain extensions. When a file is missing, the error message is about a missing file without an extension.  `Latexmk` sees the error message and has to know what extensions are relevant, so that it can try to make the missing file by a custom dependency. The default extensions differ between `latex` and `pdflatex` etc.  I made a general purpose method for handling this issue, and it seemed useful to document the subroutines and variables used internally. The reason is that there is are at least two standard packages (`graphics` and `graphicx`) that allow the user to configure the list of default graphics extensions, and a corresponding user configuration of `latexmk` would be useful.

Comment: Thanks very much for this authoritative and complete answer, as well as for all your work on latexmk! You are right of course that my actual latexmkrc does contain the add_cus_dep line; somehow I inadvertently omitted it when I was posting the question.